# GWT development mode not working on my mac

Tags: gwt, maven, maven-3

I have problems running my GWT app in debug mode using maven 3. Hosted mode works just fine when I try

```
mvn gwt:run
```

on the command line. When I try

```
mvn gwt:debug
```

the "Development Mode" app is loaded, but when I press "Launch Default Browser" it start's loading but then it just hangs forever. Usually I end this mode via Ctrl+c on the command line, but even this is not working and I have to kill the process manually.

I also tried to increase maxPermSize and Xmx without any effect.

```
mvn -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs='-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xmx1024M' gwt:debug
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes not. When I tried this, I had 4 GB of free RAM available.

Does anyone knows what the problem could be? Any tips are much appreciated.

Cheers,
Markus

Comment: Can you post a stack trace of the hanging Java process? Also, have you tried copying the URL and pasting it into Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: Yes I tried copying the URL and paste it into Firefox, no difference and I can not post a stack trace, because, there are no Exceptions shown on command line.

Comment: So Firefox hangs? Then try Chrome. In an related notes, perhaps there's some sort of firewall blocking connection. Can you access 9997 on your local machine ( or whatever the DevMode port is for you ) ?

Comment: Ok, debugging in Chrome works. I never tried this, because, I work in team where different OSs are used and my colleagues prefer Firefox and the gecko engine was the one and only user agent defined in GWT module config. I changed it locally and now I can debug. Thank you very much for this hint :)

Comment: Great! For easier discovery , I've posted this as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with Firefox. Try using Chrome. The GWT team might be interested in your specific problem, as this might indicate an error in the GWT plugin for Firefox.

Comment: If this answer is the correct one, you should upvote it and accept it.